# Power bi - Unable to set refresh for Web anonymous connection in Power bi Server

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I'm relatively new to Power bi and my problem is:

I was able to connect and refresh the data connection as anonymous from a Web connection in Power Bi Desktop.

However when I am trying to schedule the refresh to the same report on Power BI Server (after publishing it), it is returning me the following error.

Why is that? How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Is this API is publicly available?